# Intersection Observer like api for a fixed point

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

I recently learned about [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), and I am wondering if something like this is possible either with IntersectionObserver or a different api.

I want to be able to define a fixed horizontal line on my root view

```
<div className="horz_observer" />
.horz_observer {
   position: fixed;
   top: 20vh: 
   width: 100%
 }
```

I would like to trigger an event every time something crosses that that line.

I tried doing

```
rootView = document.querySelector(".horz_observer"); 
observer = new IntersectionObserver(rootView, callback);
observer.observe(someOtherItem)
```

Problem is that IntersectionObserver only allows a parent component to be a rootview.

Is it possible to do what I want using IOs, or is there a better solution.